# A simple sum of combination of word ' STATISTICS '

Tags: permutations, combinations

In how many ways we can choose 4 letters from the word 'STATISTICS' ??

Comment: Does order of selection matter?  **Hint:** count how many ways you can do so if all four letters selected are different.  Add this to the number of ways you can do so if only three distinct letters are used (2-1-1).  Add this to the number of ways you can do so if only two distinct letters are used (3-1 or 2-2).  Add this to the number of ways you can do so if all four letters are the same.

Comment: Order is not the matter... But i need a complete process with answer...

Comment: In my book the answer is 34.. but i can't understand how it is possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have A, C, (II), (SSS), (TTT). Total 5 letters.

a) All four letters distinct.

$\binom{5}{4}$ = 5

b) 2 letters are alike.

$\binom{3}{1}\cdot \binom{4}{2}$ = 18

c) 2 letters are alike and 2 are distinct.

$\binom{3}{2}$ = 3

d) 3 alike letters and 1 distinct letter.

$\binom{2}{1}\cdot \binom{4}{1}$ = 10

So we have = 5 + 18 + 3 + 8 = 34

Comment: Your case $d$ has an error in it.  $3$ alike letters and $1$ distinct letter, you cannot pick the same letter for the distinct letter as was picked for the three alike letters.  There are in fact only four available letters for the $1$ distinct letter once you have picked the letter used for the three alike.  This also does not differ greatly enough from the already present and correct answer to have warranted reposting what is essentially the same thing as what someone else had already done.

Comment: @JMoravitz I started typing answer before than him but because of some problem I posted late here. And other user also has some mistake in his answer and you are correcting that. And in my case you are down voting.

Answer (score 2):

letters present in 'STATISTICS' are SSS,TTT,II,C,A

form cases which include $(1)$ all different letters $(2)$ $2$ same two different letters $(3)$ two same of one kind and two some of other kind $(4)$ three same and one different

$(1)$ number of combination $\displaystyle \binom{5}{4}$

$(2)$ number of combination $\displaystyle \binom{3}{1}\cdot \binom{4}{2}$

$(3)$ number of combination $\displaystyle \binom{3}{2}$

$(4)$ number of combination $\displaystyle \binom{2}{1}\cdot \binom{4}{1}$

Total combination is to add all cases